# Getting list of coordinates (lat,long) from OSMNX Geoseries

Tags: python, geopandas, osmnx

I would like to calculate the shortest path between a list of destinations and an origin. But first I need to find the nodes closest to my destinations. I am getting the list of destinations from OSMNX function for a set of Points of Interests (geometries_from_place).

```
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import networkx as nx
print(ox.__version__)
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
Kinshasa = [ "Kisenso, Mont Amba, 31, Democratic Republic of the Congo",
"N'djili, Tshangu, Democratic Republic of the Congo",
"Kinshasa, Democratic Republic of the Congo"]
G_Kinshasa = ox.graph.graph_from_place(Kinshasa, simplify=True, network_type='drive')
tags2 = {'amenity' : ['hospital','university','social_facility'],
        'landuse' : ['retail', 'commercial'],
         'shop' : ['water','bakery']}
POIS = ox.geometries_from_place(Kinshasa, tags2, which_result=1)
Nearest_Nodes = ox.get_nearest_nodes(G_Kinshasa, POIS['geometry'][x],POIS[geometry][y])
```

How can I get a list of tules of lats and longs from the POIS['geometry'] object which is a GeoSeries to pass it to get_nearest_nodes in the last line of code above?
Here is a sample of output of POIS['geometry']:

```
Out[10]: 
0                             POINT (15.34802 -4.39344)
1                             POINT (15.34074 -4.41001)
2                             POINT (15.34012 -4.40466)
3                             POINT (15.34169 -4.40443)
4                             POINT (15.35278 -4.40812)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal reproducible solution (OSM cannot geocode your place queries in their current form, so I picked one that works just for demonstration purposes). Note that I specify the `balltree` method to find nearest nodes, as you are working with an unprojected graph and unprojected points.

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

place = 'Berkeley, CA, USA'
G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive')

tags = {'amenity' : ['hospital','university','social_facility'],
        'landuse' : ['retail', 'commercial'],
        'shop' : ['water','bakery']}
gdf = ox.geometries_from_place(place, tags)

centroids = gdf.centroid
X = centroids.x
Y = centroids.y

nn = ox.get_nearest_nodes(G, X, Y, method='balltree')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list op tuples with a simple lambda function.
I didn't test against the performance with respect to other possible solutions but for a 5000 row x 9 col. geodataframe it takes about 120 ms on a moderate desktop PC.

```
pointlist = list(POIS.geometry.apply(lambda x: ( x.x, x.y )))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. I get an error that 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'x'

Comment: I didn't recognize that you're using geometries_from_place method of osmnx, it will return polygons/multipolygons instead of points. You should use a function returning points or define a function calculating x,y from polygons like getting centroid.

Comment: I am getting points of interests from the function (geometries_from_place), so I do have POINTS as my geometry type. It is just that I cannot access the x and y within those points. When I insert type(POIS.geometry[1]) in Python it returns shapely.geometry.point.Point